# gameObject.GetComponent<T> != null is always true. How?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

1. I have a list of 3 game objects. Only ONE game object has a Light component attached.
2. I'm iterating through the list of all game objects like this

   ```
     foreach (var eachGameObject in objs) //eachGamObject represents one of the three game objects in a list.
   ```
3. in foreach I'm checking eachGameObject if it has a T type component attached, like this

> `if(eachGameObject.GetComponent<T>()  != null)`

4. "T" is a generic type. It can be any component. In my case I'm trying to find a GameObject with a Light component attached in the Scene.

The problem:

Even tho only ONE game object has a Light component attached, the "if" in point 3 always executes and its never NULL.

How? I'm always passing "Light" as "T" and obviously only ONE game object has Light component attached.

It's driving me crazy, any help much appriciated!

This is full function:

```
 public List<T> FindInScene<T>()
    {
        var objs = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var eachGameObject in objs)
        {
            if (eachGameObject.GetComponent<T>() != null)
            {
                list.Add(eachGameObject.GetComponent<T>());
            }

        }

        return list;
    }
```

and in the same (Monobehaviour class) I'm testing it like this:

> private void Start()    {
> List lights = FindInScene();
> Debug.Log(lights.Count);
> }

The "Count" is always 3 (equal to the game objects in the Scene).

Comment: I am 100% sure this is not full function. And if all the 'if' statements were executed, what's inside the list?

Comment: What Object is the function returning, if it isn't a null; And how is `eachGameObject` assigned?

Comment: Id guess the 2 blocks of code should be mixed. But its not our job to guess how your code is. Please produce a minimal viable example

Comment: Agree, this was not full function. For some reason i didn't paste it well. I've updated the function now ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Add where (generic type constraint),like this:

```
   public List<T> FindInScene<T>() where T :Component
    {
        var objs = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var eachGameObject in objs)
        {
            if (eachGameObject.GetComponent<T>() != null)
            {
                list.Add(eachGameObject.GetComponent<T>());
            }

        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, this one works and it will be an accepted answer. But I'm baffled why in my case it doesn't? Can you explain why it works if I put a Component constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if this works:

```
private void Start()
{
    List<Light> lights = FindInScene<Light>();
    Debug.Log(lights.Count);
}

public List<T> FindInScene<T>()
{
    var objs = FindObjectsOfType<GameObject>();
    List<T> list = new List<T>();
    if(objs != null && objs.Length > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (objs[i].GetComponent<T>() != null)
            {
                list.Add(objs[i].GetComponent<T>());
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your code and even after that it doesn't work. The count I get is "3". (equal to the GameObjects in the scene found).